# How do I construct a test case for this Code? What's wrong with my testFindEmployeeByID?

Tags: java, testing, junit

How do I construct a test case for this code? Please check my TestCase sample at the bottom. What's wrong with my testFindEmployeeByID?

```
public Employee findEmployeeByID(int employeeID) throws HRSSystemException{
    Employee result = null;
    try {
        PreparedStatement pStmt = conn
                .prepareStatement("select * from Employee where ID = ?");
        pStmt.setInt(1, employeeID);

        ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            result = new EmployeeImpl(rs.getInt("ID"), 
                        rs.getString("FIRSTNAME"),
                        rs.getString("LASTNAME"), 
                        rs.getInt("LEVEL"));

        }
        rs.close();
        pStmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new HRSSystemException(HRSSystemException.ERROR_FIND_EMPLOYEE_ID,
                e);
    }
    return result;  
}
```

Test Case:

```
public void testFindEmployeeByID(){
    testFindEmployeeByID abc = new testFindByEmployeeID();
    Employee e = abc.findEmployeeByID(employeeID);
    assertEquals(1,e.getID);
}
```

Comment: What's employeeId? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

This part in the `testFindEmployeeByID()`-method looks wrong:

```
testFindEmployeeByID abc = new testFindByEmployeeID();
```

Is `testFindEmployeeByID` the test class name also? You probably meant to instantiate the class containing the actual `findEmployeeByID`-method.